# Can Qubes-OS be used without a mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qubes-os

Does Qubes-OS support keyboard shortcuts well enough to use it without a mouse? I read that dom0 maintains the desktop environment, which can be KDE or xfce, so can I assume the shortcuts will be the same as those in KDE or xfce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the keyboard shortcuts and customization options from the corresponding version of Fedora (that dom0 is based on) are all available.